# Spring boot 2.2.9 Hibernate Error: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have googled and went over all existing answers on StackOverflow for the error I am seeing. I tried applying all the suggestions and still can't get rid of this dreaded error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:143)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:475)
        at com.myComp.core.persistence.HibernateUtils.find(HibernateUtils.java:82)
```

I am using Spring boot 2.2.9 with spring data jpa. I am using stratight hibernate implementation using SessionFactory to get my session. I have declated @Transactional annotation on my Service and calling sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() from inside the Dao classes and that's where I am running into this error.

Here is my Spring xml configuration (I am not using Java Config yet)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mv" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">
      <context:component-scan base-package="com.myComp.core.persistence" />
      <context:annotation-config />
      <bean id="dataSourceassets" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/assets" />
        <property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <property name="password" value="postgres" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="6" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="6" />
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="10000" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="60000" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="30000" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="select 1" />
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="false" />
      </bean>
      <bean id="sessionFactoryassets" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean" destroy-method="destroy">
        <property name="dataSource">
          <ref bean="dataSourceassets" />
        </property>
        <property name="mappingResources" value="/com/myComp/core/persistence/assets/ObjectMappings.xml" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
          <props>
          <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
          </props>
        </property>
      </bean>
      <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
          <ref bean="sessionFactoryassets" />
        </property>
      </bean>
      <bean id="daoHelperassets" class="com.myComp.core.persistence.assets.AssetsDAOHelper">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
          <ref bean="sessionFactoryassets" />
        </property>
      </bean>
      <bean id="masterAssetApi" class="com.myComp.core.persistence.assets.LocalAssetApiImpl">
        <property name="daoHelper">
          <ref bean="daoHelperassets" />
        </property>
      </bean>
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
    </beans>
```

I have CGLIB, Spring aspectj on my classpath. I am running this with java 1.8
I have tried Transaction annotation config with mode = proxy and also aspectj. I have even tried proxy-target-class = true and false. All my attempts failed.
I am extracting the Spring managed bean "masterAssetApi" (instance of servic class LocalAssetApiImpl where @Transaction is decalred)  outside of my Spring container and calling my Service methods in my main application. This is not a Spring App like regular spring app.
Here is an example code

```
AssetApiImplInterface master = springContext.getBean("masterAssetApi");
master.getUser("20"); 
//getUser service method has read-only=true with @Transactional annotation
```

Here is HibernateUtils code

```
   public <T> java.util.List<T>  find(final SessionFactory sessionFactory, final String queryString, final Map<String, Object> args, Class<T> cls, final String extendedErrorMessage)
      throws PersistenceException
   {
      try
      {
         try
         {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query<T> qry = session.createQuery(queryString);
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry: args.entrySet()) {
               qry.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            List<T> ret = qry.list();
            return ret;
         }
         catch (final HibernateException exception) {
            throw SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(exception);
         }
      }
      catch (final BadSqlGrammarException bsg)
      {
         tracer.exception(bsg);
         throw new PersistenceException(PersistenceException.SESSIONFAILURE, extendedErrorMessage, bsg);
      }
      catch (final DataAccessException dae)
      {
         tracer.exception(dae);
         throw new PersistenceException(PersistenceException.SESSIONFAILURE, extendedErrorMessage, dae);
      }
      catch (final Exception ex)
      {
         tracer.exception(ex);
         try
         {
            Thread.sleep(exceptionHiatus);
         }
         catch (final InterruptedException e)
         {
            tracer.debug("Slumber interrupted " + e.getMessage());
         }
         throw new PersistenceException(PersistenceException.SESSIONFAILURE, extendedErrorMessage, ex);
      }
   }
```

And here is the call stacktrace.

```
ERROR 2020-10-06 20:20:41.123 [tomcat-p2p-23-Execute] com.myCorp.core.persistence.HibernateUtils:  Exception:
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:300)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.HibernateUtils.find(HibernateUtils.java:91)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.Utils.find(Utils.java:157)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.SubGridImpl.getSubGridImpl(SubGridImpl.java:606)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.SubGridImpl.getSubGrid(SubGridImpl.java:498)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.AssetsDAOHelper.getSubGrid(AssetsDAOHelper.java:224)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.LocalAssetApiImpl.getSubGrid(LocalAssetApiImpl.java:405)
        at com.myCorp.core.persistence.assets.LooseAssetApiManagerImpl.getSubGrid(LooseAssetApiManagerImpl.java:406)
```

@Transactional annotation is around LocalAssetApiImpl.getSubGrid(..)

Note: I am using BeanFactory IOC container to load my Spring Xml instead of ApplicationContext. Do you think this might be the problem?

Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Show please code of your `HibernateUtils.find` method.

Comment: Thanks @GordonfromBlumberg for your quick response. I edited my original question to add complete find code.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem, I ran into. Using BeanFactory was the problem.
As soon, as I switched to ApplicationContext IOC, my problem went away.